# Does Offensive Guard trigger only for monster attacks?

Tags: monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

I know, the question might look silly. However, since there are non-monster attacks which trigger the guard and/or Divine Blessing, I am curious whether it triggers for:

- environments (e.g., falling boulders)
- friendlies' attacks
- bombs
- other damage sources which can be guarded

Some digging revealed that [the time bomb in the practice area does not apply](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunterWorld/comments/d5ebnq/is_offensive_guard_work_on_the_bomb_in_the/), but I want to know a more specific answer, especially given that there was [a tactic involving self-activation of Enraged Guard using a bomb](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/6jfgik/til_enraged_guard_has_a_trick/)<sup>*1</sup>, and if bombs still apply for Offensive Guard, the same strategy could be applied for e.g., Sword and Shield.

<sub>*1: For *World* newcomers, Enraged Guard was a Counter Thrust-like stance which, instead of advancing into a thrust, just granted the hunter a Offensive Guard-like buff. Thus, there was a strategy of just exploding the Large Barrel Bomb and canceling it into Enraged Guard to get the benefit of it.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After over a hundred hours in Iceborne playing Lance with "Offensive Guard" a routine part of my armor, I have never been able to trigger Offensive Guard from the Environment, fellow hunters, or Bombs.

While Anecdotal Evidence is obviously not the same as a hard confirmation, I suspect the answer to your question is: Yes -- only monsters can trigger Offensive Guard.